# How can I send any key using robot class when workstation is locked

Tags: java

I am trying to send key when my workstation is locked in windows 7 by using java and task scheduler but not able to do so. Help me please.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

Thread.sleep(200);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(200);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(200);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(200);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(200);
```

it's not working when my system is locked. but I want to send tab key when workstation is locked.

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to accomplisch?

Comment: can i send password to in batch file to unlock system

Comment: so is there any way i can send key through batch file

Comment: Not easily no. You'll have to mimic what psexec does when creating a process on the Secure Desktop. This means at least being able to run as system. You might get some pointers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000071/how-do-i-send-keyboard-mouse-input-to-the-windows-logon-screen) question.

Comment: actually i am trying to creating a task which will open browser and upload a file according to robot class. this task will run in continuation of 2 hours but when i am not using my system then it has been locked automatically due to security purpose that is why i need to unlock my system automatically. I tried to send key of my user account password  with java but its not working at the time of logon so there is any way to logon system automatically with password.

Comment: Much more reliable would be to upload the file using the available http classes in java *(I'm no java developer, no idea how they are called)* and have that running as a scheduled task.

Comment: i dont have ftp path of website i just have login user id and password that's why i am not able to upload file with http class in java

Comment: and even i don't have administrator rights of website

Comment: I'm no expert on this but if you can use a browser to upload files, it seems to me you should be able to use http classes to do the same.

Comment: I would recommend asking a new question to that effect